# Swagger UI пароль для показа документации

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, swaggerui, swashbuckle

Я пытаюсь сделать документацию для апи (ASP.net core). она должна быть приватной и доступной по авторизации. Использую Swagger, в сети много примеров как добавить аутентификацию в Swagger, но это примеры для того что бы добавить аутентификацию для RestAPi, подскажите есть ли способ поставить пароль на саму графику SwaggerUI ?

Comment: Конечно очень интересно. По сути это статичный сайт который может формировать fetch запрос глядя на документацию. Так вот если забыть про это и думать что существует статичная страница и нужно ограничить доступ то в чем проблема. Берите роутите и слушайте нужный вам роут и не прропускайте на страницу без авторизации

Comment: @AzizUmarov я делаю редерект на базовую аутентификацию. в режиме дебага все работает, после клика на вход, похоже не приходит заголовок с аутентификацией

Comment: Заголовок вам зачем. Все данные по аутентификации хранится в сессии. Если сессия авторизована то дальше уже пользуйтесь документацией и прочими благами

Comment: В заголовке базовая аутентификация передает пароль и логин